# is it possible to have more implementation of annotated rest interface?

Tags: rest, java-ee-7

is it possible to have more implementation of annotated REST interface so app. server decides which implementation to use e.g. concerning its @Priority?

example:

```
@Path("endpoint")
public interface Endpoint {
    @GET("{id}")
    RetVal get(Integer id);
}

@Priority(100)
public class EndpointImpl implements Endpoint {
    RetVal get(Integer id) {
        return new RetVal();
    }
}

@Priority(200)
public class ExtendedEndpointImpl implements Endpoint {
    ExtendedRetVal get(Integer id) {
        return new ExtendedRetVal(); // class ExtendedRetVal extends RetVal
    }
}
```